# Can I use HP:s HTML config on macOs Sierra somehow?

Tags: macos, network, printing

I've bought a HP Laserjet Pro M12 (M11-M13 series). I'm trying to setup the wireless part. No firmware has been released for Sierra yet. I have installed the drivers 10.11 instead. When I click open HTML config, I get sent to http://localhost:5050/SSI/index.htm, it seems to be a webhost provided by the printer via USB.

The first page I visit renders fine, but when I click any link the page breaks and it says safari can't connect to the server "localhost".

Is there some way to get this working? I've tried other browsers.

Comment: Can you check (with `lsof`) which process is using port 5050?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this by replacing localhost:5050 with 0.0.0.0:5050 in the domain name, ie  http://0.0.0.0:5050/SSI/index.htm

Not sure why it worked but it did :P